# How to prevent gnus from unlocking my GnuPG key

Tags: gnus, gpg, authinfo

I'm using Gnus to read newsgroups via nntp.  I am using mu4e to read and send e-mails.  My e-mail server credentials are stored in `~/.authinfo.gpg` so that mu4e can access them.

My problem is that whenever I open Gnus for the first time, I get asked the passphrase of the GnuPG key used to encrypt `~/.authinfo.gpg`.  It seems that Gnus wants to open that file by default, even though it does not need any credentials to read my nntp sources.

How can disable this automatic opening of `~/.authinfo.gpg` whenever I open Gnus?